# Remembering Chemical formula

Tags: everyday-chemistry

How do you all remember the name of chenical formula of Glucose, Lime, Vinegar ... etc. becasue these substances have big big chemical formula. So, How do I remember their chemical formula?

Comment: Why do you think lime and vinegar have big formulas ? BTW, vinegar is not a substance, it is basically diluted water solution of acetic acid. It is remembered by the same way as you remember things you cannot derive from the general principles. Or in case of substances, from their systematic names. You just know simple things from your heart over time, if you are a chemist. You look up for complex things if you need them.

Comment: Practice.$\mathstrut$

Comment: It is like a language. A logical language.

Comment: How can I know What Is the Chemical formula of Glucose? How do you derive the formula?

Comment: You don't. This is not a thing that can be deduced by logic. Just read the formula in a book and memorize it.

Comment: @Khan_Jamal Chemistry is in many aspects as learning other language. There  is many things you cannot derive, you just remember them or look them up.